# ¿Cuál es la equivalencia en Java para guardar datos como en Python?

Tags: java, python, arraylist

¿Cómo guardar datos de una variable en un array en *Java*, al igual que se hace en *Python*?

```
num = int(input("digite un numero :))
lista = []
lista.append(num)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y todo depende de que tipo sea lista, pero si es un array (declarado con tipo y tamaño), seria lista[0] = num?

Comment: Revisa la [interfaz `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) para ver si es lo que necesitas para tu caso. Java tiene varios objetos para guardar grupos o estructuras de datos y el que uses dependerá también de la forma en que vas a consumir esos datos. En en el enlace te indica las principales posibilidades que te da `List`: acceso según la posición, búsqueda, iteracción, vista por rangos...

Answer (score 2):

Los arrays en Java, al igual que en C, C++ y lenguajes de la familia, no son de longitud variable: si no sabes cual es el tamaño necesario antes de crearlos, tendrás que elegir una solución:

- Trabajar con arrays, pero cuando necesites un tamaño mayor al actual, necesitarás crear un array más grande y copiar todos los datos al nuevo.
- Usar una clase que implemente `List` y permita tamaños variables, como puede ser `ArrayList` o `LinkedList` (dependiendo de tus necesidades una es más eficiente que la otra).

Comment: falto agregar que amblas ArrayList o LinkedList usan el método **add()** para añadir los elementos

Comment: Considero que el API de la interfaz es irrelevante para el objetivo de la pregunta y es fácilmente consultable en la documentación. En estos casos lo complicado suele ser saber qué consultar

Answer (score 0):

simple, pero mejor usar un [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843371/4668184)

```
int[] Lista = new int[9];
lista[i] = num;
```

imagino que usarás un do while para llenar el array

*UPDATE* Escribí a la carrera la respuesta pero mas o menos realice algo para que entendieras como se adiciona datos al array, me confundí con el ArrayList

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Lista = new int[9];
        int num=0;
        int i=0;
          System.out.print( "digite un numero :" + " 999 para salir" );
          while(num!=999)
          {
           num =  Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
           Lista[i]=num;
           i++;
          }
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/AdmirableSurprisedSoftwareengineer

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que guardará son múltiples valores sin conocer la longitud, lo recomendable será que use **ArrayList**. Su aplicación es rápida y sencilla:

*Sintaxis*: `ArrayList<'Tipo de dato'> list = new ArrayList<'Tipo de dato'>();`

**Ejemplo de adición en el listado**:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
```

De igual modo también lo podría hacer con objetos creados por usted mismo, que en realidad es su uso más común.

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(new Object());
```

Y cuando quiera **eliminar** un elemento lo haría así:

```
list.remove(index) // index: índice del elemento
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *De igual modo también lo podría hacer con objetos, que en realidad es su uso más común*? Las listas **sólo** trabajan con objetos

Comment: Cierto, lo que quiero decir son objetos creados por el mismo, lo aclararé. Muchas gracias, @Pablo.